# How to return django queryset from model method to template?

Tags: python, django

i would like to get all children recursively from concrete object, until now i have this..

INFO:

- object 1

  - id: 15
  - parent_id: None
- object

  - id: 16
  - parent_id: 15
- object

  - id: 17
  - parent_id: 16

children of the object with id = 15
-> [object: id: 16, object: id: 17]

children of the object with id = 17
-> []

models.py:

```
class CustomModel(models.Model):
  ...
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='child', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

  def get_child(self, childs=[]):

    child = CustomModel.objects.filter(parent_id=self.id).first()

    if childs is None:
        childs = []

    if child is not None:
        childs.append(child.id)
        child.get_child(childs)

    else:
      result = CustomModel.objects.filter(id__in=childs)
      print(result)
      return result
```

view.html:

```
def detail(request, id=None):

  element = CustomModel.objects.get(id=id)

  return render(request, ‘file.html’, {
    ‘element’: element
  })
```

file.html:

```
{{ element.get_child }}
```

or

```
{% for child in element.get_child %}
```

On print debug point i can see all children objects but in template appears as none

Anybody could help me please ?
Happy new year everyone.

Comment: Please share your view and your template too

Comment: Small improvement note (not directly related to programming): the plural of "child" is "children" and not "childs".

Comment: Just saw that in your ```get_child method``` ```None``` is returned if child is not None. Is that what you want?

Comment: i don't know if have proposed well recursive method @Chris. Post edited with more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!

```
class CustomModel(models.Model):

  ...

  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

  def get_sons(self, sons=None):

    son = CustomModel.objects.filter(parent_id=self.id).first()

    if sons is None:
      sons = []

    if son is None:
      return sons

    else:
      sons.append(son)
      return son.get_sons(sons)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your code from this

```
{{ element.childs }}
```

to use the correct method name that you defined, like this:

```
{{ element.get_child }}
```

or this:

```
{% for child in element.get_child %}
    {{ child }}
{% endfor %}
```

Does that work?